# object tag data url not working in Firefox browser

Tags: html

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="myExperience" width="750" height="330" class="BrightcoveExperience BrightcoveExperienceID_000" seamlesstabbing="undefined" data="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?&amp;width=750&amp;height=330&amp;flashID=myExperience&amp;identifierClassName=BrightcoveExperienceID_4215&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;playerID=00000&amp;playerKey=OxYE~%2CghzTVE6blfqQ7g0q_-kjo8tx5ZAtjmpX&amp;isVid=true&amp;isUI=true&amp;dynamicStreaming=true&amp;autoStart=true&amp;debuggerID=&amp;videoID=0000&amp;%40videoPlayer=481093701&amp;startTime=1482473441585/?forceHTML=true"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
 <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />
 <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
 <param name="seamlessTabbing" value="false">
 <param name="swliveconnect" value="true">
 <param name="wmode" value="window">
 <param name="quality" value="high">
 <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF">
 <param name="forceHTML" value="true" />
</object>
```

> but this code working in crome and ie.

Comment: which version of firefox are you using?

Comment: I have used firefox Version 48.0.2

Comment: If I put your code in a snippet, it doesn't do anything in either browser. Can you post a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: it might be because flash is phased out of all major browsers... yay!

Answer (score 0):

I get a "video not available" message in all browsers using your html and, equally, get the same message when invoking the URL imbedded in your html.

```
http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?&amp;width=750&amp;height=330&amp;flashID=myExperience&amp;identifierClassName=BrightcoveExperienceID_4215&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;playerID=00000&amp;playerKey=OxYE~%2CghzTVE6blfqQ7g0q_-kjo8tx5ZAtjmpX&amp;isVid=true&amp;isUI=true&amp;dynamicStreaming=true&amp;autoStart=true&amp;debuggerID=&amp;videoID=0000&amp;%40videoPlayer=481093701&amp;startTime=1482473441585/?forceHTML=true
```

Are you certain that the flash object which you're attempting to load actually exists?